# SQL LIKE wildcard returning rows without match

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table that's used for logging. It has two columns:

```
queueid (int)
message (nvarchar(MAX))
```

I am looking for rows with a specific userid (seven digits) in the message (output for the log).

When I run

```
SELECT queueid, message
FROM  [dbname].[dbo].[log]
WHERE
  [dbname].[dbo].[log].[message] LIKE '%1597498%';
```

SSMS returns 105 rows. However most of the values for message do not contain that string. If I select the message column in the results and paste the text into an editor, there are less than 50 matches for that string. I get this result with other user id values as well.

I thought the LIKE syntax was fairly straightforward. Is there another issue that might be at play?

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: SSMS only displays the rows - *Sql Server* returns them; SSMS also truncates data so depending on how large the string is you may well not see it in SSMS - for a candidate row with the problem see what you get from *charindex* perhaps?

Comment: `SELECT queueid, message, SUBSTRING(message, PATINDEX('%1597498%', message)-10, 50) FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I was qualifying for specificity but tried it without as well. I'll only use alias in the future.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-)?

Comment: Thanks Stu and Aaron. That's the issue; running Aaron's query showed the subset of information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't lie - it's not going to return a row that doesn't match the predicate you've specified.

SSMS may hide the truth, though, since its grid and text displays limit the amount of text that will show.

So, it's likely that the problem is just that the data is there in the table but not in the subset of the value that is shown in SSMS.

To see that the data is there, just return that portion:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT queueid, message, pos = patindex('%1597498%',message)
  FROM dbo.[log]
  WHERE message LIKE N'%1597498%'
)
SELECT queueid, 
  SUBSTRING(message, CASE WHEN pos > 10 THEN pos - 10 ELSE 1 END, 50),
  message
FROM src;
```

- [Working example in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UxRitN5P).

Comment: Thank you. I assumed it didn't lie but then couldn't figure out where the results were. The message column is too freeform to easily notice that the column results in SSMS weren't complete. I appreciate your explanation and sample query.